# Managing gem versions/dependencies for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, dependencies, bundle

Just a bit of background, I come from a strong C#/staticly typed background. Therefore I tend to think in terms of .dlls. So if I was working in a project, I'd reference my required dlls and that would be that.

Being new to Ruby and Rails I find I might be doing something wrong. For example, I create a Rails app at home using the gems I have locally. Using a different computer (say a work computer) I attempt to work on the project only to find I'm using different versions of the gems. After carrying out a bundle install I'm back to a working project.

The issue I have with this is that my gem library becomes 'messy'. I end up with several versions of the same gem. Is this the way others work? When using a gem (from a require) will it default to the latest version? I feel as if I'm not managing the dependencies correctly, though as I've mentioned I'm new to the world of Ruby.

Should I just include my dependencies, then perform a bundle install each time I have different/missing dependencies? What happens if I wish to upgrade to a newer version of a gem? Would it be a case of updating the gemfile that bundle uses and getting on with it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, bundler is the way to go to work with dependancies with Ruby on Rails. Why ? First, because it's shipped with it (at least for version 3.0). Second, because it's simple as hell (unlike maven with Java).

A non exhaustive list of feature :

- it lets you declare one or many gem repository to fetch gems from
- to group your dependencies by environment (development, production...)
- to specify version you'd like

and so on. For more on this, check this http://gembundler.com/rationale.html

**Regarding your question** : yes, bundler will take the latest version available is none is specified.

Also, I would add a disavantage : you cannot specify a gem version depending on the OS. For example, nokogiri has a linux version AND a win version.

Comment: Nice one. I was unaware you could omit the versions in the bundle file. Solves my issue of the build breaking for version differences of 0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

The default behaviour when requiring a module in a gem is to assume you want the latest version of the gem if you have more than one installed. You can change this by [specifying which version you](https://bundler.io/man/gemfile.5.html#VERSION) want in a specific application like this:

```
gem "rails", "2.3.8"
```

Before you require anything from the gem. This ensures that this application will use the specified version of the gem, even if a newer one is installed.

You can of course clean out obsolete versions of your installed gems whenever you don't need them again, or if you use bundler consistently: just wipe everything and run bundler again to get just your required gems installed.

Another useful tool is the [Ruby Version Manager](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/) (RVM), in addition to handling different versions of ruby it provides a feature called gemsets which allows you to isolate different applications or environments from eachother. That is App A can have its separate gemset with all its required gems, and App B have another gemset with only its required gems. This will reduce the clutter in your dependencies quite a bit.

Comment: First link is broken